# Python tflearn: Load a zip file with folders containing images

Tags: python, machine-learning, tflearn

I have a zip file which has several hundred folders in it each containing 3-4 images. I want to use these images as the training data to recognize faces. How do I load these images? 
And, what is the optimal way to load datasets? As a pkl file or something else?

Comment: How do I load the list of images as the dataset? What, specifically, is the syntax for it?

Answer (score 0):

I would unzip the file first then you have a folder structure and then you can easily do something like this:

```
import os
imgs = []
for directory in os.listdir(base_directory):
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
         imgs.append(scipy.misc.imread(base_directory + "/" + directory + "/" + file)
```

in case you have other files in there you can use `os.path.isdir` to check if it is a dir and `file.endswith` to check if it is a file with your image ending.

Comment: That seems okay. But how do I set imgs as the dataset? Like how do I make sure it reads the images from the list? And how efficient is reading from a list?

Comment: Is it something like 'X, Y, X_train, Y_train = load(imgs)'